# Performance comparison MPI vs OpenMP

Tags: c++, performance, time, mpi, openmp

I have a very strange problem.
I even do not know if I can provide you all the information you need to answer my question; in case something is missing, please let me know.

I run a code like this using MPI:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include "mkl.h"
double *gradient_D = new double[K*M];
double *DX = new double[M*N];
double gradientD_time = MPI_Wtime();
for (int j = 0; j < K; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        gradient_D[j*M+i] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            gradient_D[i+M*j] += DX[i+k*M];
        }   
    }  
double gradientD_total_time = (MPI_Wtime() - gradientD_time);
printf("Gradient D total = %f \n", gradientD_total_time);
```

It odes not really matter the meaning of the code: I am just running three for loops and evaulating the CPU time.
In the cmake I wrote the following commands:

```
project(mpi_algo)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "mpicxx")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-cxx=icpc -mkl=sequential")
add_executable(mpi_algo main.cpp)
```

and I run the code:

```
mpirun -np 1 ./mpi_algo
```

After that, I run a similar code in which I do the same operations, but using OpenMP instead of MPI:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include "mkl.h"
double *gradient_D = new double[K*M];
double *DX = new double[M*N];
double gradientD_time = omp_get_wtime();
for (int j = 0; j < K; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        gradient_D[j*M+i] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            gradient_D[i+M*j] += DX[i+k*M];
        }   
    }  
double gradientD_total_time = (omp_get_wtime() - gradientD_time);
printf("Gradient D total = %f \n", gradientD_total_time);
```

You can see that there are small differences in the code.
This is the cmake:

```
project(openmp_algo)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "icc")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-qopenmp -mkl=sequential")
add_executable(openmp_algo main.cpp)
```

and I run the code:

./openmp_algo

Now, what I can not explain is that the code with MPI takes about 1 second to run. The other one, that should be the same, takes about 20 seconds.

Could you please someone explain me why?

EDIT: the constants M, N, n, k do not matter for understanding the issue. They just define the dimension of the arrays.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations on? Without them, it's a meaningless comparison; one compiler might default to some level of optimization and optimize out most of the loop (since the results are unused, the loop could actually be dropped entirely with higher optimization levels), the other might be doing all the work then throwing it away. It doesn't help that this isn't a [MCVE]; we don't know where `gradient_D_loc` is defined, what any of the constants are, etc.

Comment: I do not know to what you are referring to.
Actually in the entire code the result of that loop is used.

Comment: I edited: `gradient_D_loc` was supposed to be just `gradient_D`

Comment: Compilers take flags to enable optimization (most default to producing unoptimized code, but not all). Comparing timing results with optimizations off or at different levels won't give you useful results. For example, `icc` takes `-O#` (`#` being 0-3) for higher and higher optimization levels, plus `-fast` for "extreme optimizations". Since `mpicxx` seems to wrap `icpc` here, it would pass similar options. It looks like `-O2 -xHost` [is recommended with `icc`/`icpc`](https://www.osc.edu/book/export/html/3729).

Comment: Why do you use `icc` as C++ compiler in the OpenMP example?

Comment: I am not expert of these stuff.
I saw other people using `icc`, what is the problem with `icc` ?

Comment: @Mobius88: Technically, `icc` is the Intel *C* Compiler, while `icpc` is the Intel *C++* Compiler, and your code is C++. A lot of C compilers actually check file extensions and switch modes based on the extension, so it might not matter, it's just a little odd to ask for `icc` when you're compiling C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give much details on the environment, I will make a wild guess to try to give an explanation. First, let's make a few remarks:

- Your seemingly identical just do nothing, so a clever compiler is fully entitled to optimize away your compute loops and just do the printing;
- Your OpenMP code is compiled with a vanilla `icc` (odd choice for a C++ code BTW) which optimization level will therefore be the default `-O2` (minus the extra optimization seen as not thread-safe by default that using `-qopenmp` will disable;
- Your MPI code is compiled with a plain `mpicxx` which will call internally `icpc` as compiler.

This is the `mpicxx` that I suspect is the key here: indeed, `mpicxx`is just a wrapper to the actual compiler, which will also set some include path, some library path and list, but also might set some extra optimization options. In some cases for example, the optimization options used while installing the MPI library will be kept inside the `mpicxx` wrapper and silently used by default when compiling your codes...

So here is my guess, your `mpicxx` set among other the `-O3` optimization option and therefore, the compiler will optimize away the loop for MPI, while the default `-O2` that you get for your OpenMP code doesn't do it. Therefore, you're timing pretty-much nothing in the case of your MPI code, while you're timing the actual loop execution with your OpenMP one.

Just a guess, but that seems fair enough. A good test would be to check what a `mpicxx -cxx=icpc -show` would give you...

Comment: Ok I'll check.
But do you know how to change the two compilers in such a way the comparison between the two codes becomes reasonable.
Should I lower (I do not know how) to `-O2` `mpicxx` or should I increase to `-O3` (I do not know jow) the `icpc` compiler?